# Control a textView

Tags: android, textview

my application keeps force closing. But Eclipse shows no error or warnings

```
package com.example.pkg;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class subActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                      public void run()
                      {   final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rline1);
                          String s=(String)tv.getText();
                          tv.setText(s+"Works !");
                      }
        });
        r.start();
    }

}
```

Another Activity calls this Activity. That one has the TextView displayed. All I want to do is to change this string resource called R.string.rline1 that is being displayed on the TextView. Please tell me how to do this if there is another way

Comment: Why you need to have thread for this

Comment: Why you want this task to be execute in Thread? Any specific reason.

Comment: UI components must be updated on UI Thread!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you must need to update GUI stuffs inside UI thread else it will never work. Second thing you know how many times you are creating the instance of your text view and setting it again again, you are inside the thread and you havn't set any flag to stop your thread once you are done. E.g for UI thread :

```
        Runnable update_gui = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rline1);
              String s=(String)tv.getText();
              tv.setText(s+"Works !");

            }
        };runOnUiThread(update_gui);
```

Comment: ^Thanks. I understood it the hard way that the answer to my question is simply : You Can't. Activities that aren't in focus are not updatable :p and thanks for the runOnUiThread method. If the current activity is the current Screen, then isn't runOnUiThread simply the same as running it on onCreate method ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update your UI (with `tv.setText(s+"Works !");`) in a thread. You cannot do that. You must update your UI in the main thread. Just delete this useless Thread:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rline1);
        String s=(String)tv.getText();
        tv.setText(s+"Works !");
    }
```

***Note**: Eclipse doesn't show errors, you must open your logcat (by default in the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.)
Next time, post your logcat error when you have troubles.*

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```
     Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                  public void run()
                  {   **final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rline1);
                      String s=(String)tv.getText();
                      tv.setText(s+"Works !");**
                  }
    });
    r.start();
```

with

```
final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rline1);
                          String s=(String)tv.getText();
                          tv.setText(s+"Works !");
```